# how to map two list in a single list in python using zip() in list comprehension

Tags: python

I tried to create a list ‘name’ consisting of the combination of the first name and the second name from list 1 and 2 respectively. And want to print using zip function in list comprehension.

For e.g. if the input list is:

```
[['Ankur', 'Avik', 'Kiran', 'Nitin'], ['Narang', 'Sarkar', 'R', 'Sareen']]
```

the output list should be the list:

```
['Ankur Narang', 'Avik Sarkar', 'Kiran R', 'Nitin Sareen']
```

Comment: ... What is your *question*? This isn't a question. This is a prompt.

Comment: Trying to get in before the question is closed. Hopefully this helps: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip

Comment: Where are your stuck?

Comment: @patmcb I looked up to the docs but didn't get the idea how exactly I can do it using list comprehension

Comment: @kleerofski I was stuck using it as a list cause I was passing  two variable which was splitting the main list into two list and zip it using a single variable in loop not two like i use for i in zip(list1,list2)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I was solving problems so I can get better in python so I came across to this question which was just which making me so confused cause I have to use list comprehension I googled  even read the docs but didn't find exactly how to do it even I search it here too but didn't get the concept . but people are here helpful and rude too it has some place to make your doubts clear right ? but i don't why people get ruthless nobody  knows everything at least i was trying to solve of my own if i was lazy or just simply want answer that would be a different scenario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `map` and `zip` for this:

```
>>> data = [['Ankur', 'Avik', 'Kiran', 'Nitin'], ['Narang', 'Sarkar', 'R', 'Sareen']]
>>> list(map(' '.join, zip(*data)))
['Ankur Narang', 'Avik Sarkar', 'Kiran R', 'Nitin Sareen']
```

Answer (score 2):

map with lambda can also be used to join 2 lists. Each value from the list is passed to the lambda.

```
input_list = [['Ankur', 'Avik', 'Kiran', 'Nitin'], ['Narang', 'Sarkar', 'R', 'Sareen']]
first_name = input_list[0]
last_name = input_list[1]

name = list(map(lambda x,y: x + " " + y, first_name, last_name))

print(names)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
name = list(map(lambda x,y: x+ " " + y, first_name,last_name))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Code-only answers are not particularly helpful. Please add some descriptions of how this code solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:-

```
a = [['Ankur', 'Avik', 'Kiran', 'Nitin'], ['Narang', 'Sarkar', 'R', 'Sareen']]
res = [i + ' ' + j for i, j in zip(a[0], a[1])]
print(res)
```

Output:-

```
['Ankur Narang', 'Avik Sarkar', 'Kiran R', 'Nitin Sareen']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
input_list = [ ['Ankur', 'Avik', 'Kiran', 'Nitin'], ['Narang', 'Sarkar', 'R', 'Sareen']]
first_name = input_list[0]
last_name = input_list[1]

name = list(map(' '.join, zip(first_name,last_name)))

print(name)
```

Comment: an explanation is required

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

### You can try this using lambda function and map function. it is working

```
input_list = [ ['Ankur', 'Avik', 'Kiran', 'Nitin'], ['Narang', 'Sarkar', 'R', 'Sareen']]
first_name = input_list[0]
last_name = input_list[1]

F = lambda first_name,last_name: first_name+" "+last_name # lambda function
name = list(map(F,first_name,last_name)) # Map
print(name)
```

output:

```
['Ankur Narang', 'Avik Sarkar', 'Kiran R', 'Nitin Sareen']
```